# No Signature at the end of url using digital ocean cdn in django

Tags: django, cdn, django-storage

This is my configutation

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'keyid'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'accesskey'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'allio1'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://sfo3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'allio1.sfo3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'allio-static'


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

There is no signature at the end of the url. It is just plain url for example https://allio1.sfo3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/allio-static/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css There is no signature at the end of url and it says access denied

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue as well and it seems that indeed django-storages does not generate a signature when `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` is defined and `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL` is 'private' or None.

As suggested in this [django-storages issue](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/944#issuecomment-943687464) you could:

1. omit the `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` (or set it to None)
2. use `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3"` in order for the signed URL to work with the CDN domain.
3. later in your code replace the static URL part that contains the bucket endpoint (which will be something like `{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}`) with the `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`.

PS. Something similar is suggested in the Digital Ocean docs as well: [presigned URLs with the Spaces CDN](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/reference/s3-sdk-examples/#presigned-url).